# Global Use of Realm Instance in Swift

Tags: swift, realm

In each of my view controllers where I use Realm, I add the realm as a property to each class:

```
//Whatevs.swift
class Whatevs:NSViewController{
  let realm = try! Realm()
}
```

I then reference it throughout the class via `self.realm`.

Is there any reason not to make it a globally available instance like this?

```
//Global.swift <-- General swift file in my app
let realm = try! Realm() //<-- Not inside a class
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, it's usually discouraged from hanging onto `Realm` instances at all if it can be helped. :)

Once `Realm()` is called on a specific thread, that instance will be internally cached by Realm and the same instance will be returned on subsequent `Realm()` calls. As a result, there's no tangible performance gains from hanging onto a Realm instance as a class member like that.

If you do any kind of threaded operations in your app, you need to be careful with storing `Realm` references since calling `self.realm` on a background thread will then trigger an exception.

If you're dealing with just the default Realm, then best practice is to simply call `let realm = try! Realm()` at the time you actually need it.

If you're dealing with different types of Realms that rely on specific `Configuration` instances, then it's recommended to store those as global constants. Realm `Configuration` objects are thread-safe so they can be passed to background threads to create `Realm` instances there with no problems.

Comment: That's really interesting, thank you. So is it best to not use `Realm()` as a class property? I only do that out of convenience. Should I be nullifying or deallocating `Realm()` instances when I am done using them (like in `deinit` in a Swift class)?

Comment: My pleasure! Yeah, it's best not to store it as a class property; just call `let realm = try! Realm()` whenever you need it. Nullifying of deallocing it won't do anything immediately, but you can place `Realm()` calls inside `@autoreleaspool` blocks to force the system to free them when you're done.